# VBA Select Case Order of Execution

Tags: vba, case

The documentation for the VBA Select Case statement doesn't seem to address this question expressly, but are the Case clauses executed in order or should the code intended to be run second be placed in a separate conditional structure?

*I.e.*, If Oranges must run after Apples, is it better to do:

```
Select Case My.Property
    Case "Foo"
        Apples
    Case "Bar"
        Oranges
End Select
```

Or should it be:

```
Select Case My.Property
    Case "Foo"
        Apples
End Select

Select Case My.Property
    Case "Bar"
        Oranges
End Select
```

Thanks for any constructive input and apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Well in this case, no matter what only one will run. if you want it to test both, you would want to separate them into two `Select` Blocks, as a `Select` Block stops checking after finding it's first value.

Comment: If you want to test a property against multiple criteria, and only take the first one found to be true, use a `Select` block. Otherwise, if you're just testing several independent properties, why not use `If` statements?

Comment: `Select Case` automatically exits after a `Case` matches and executes. Independent of the `Case` number. You can also use more `Case` criteria, comma separated: `Case "Foo","Bars": x = "Fruits"`

Comment: `doesn't seem to address this question expressly` - why, it does, in the first paragraph of the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement#remarks). The first sentence says that if a block matches, only that block executes, and not any others. The third sentence says that if several blocks match, only the first match is executed.